# mod rewrite rule to include period

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What should I add the rewrite rule to include reading periods?

I have this currently on my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /user/public/index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

if i have this it works fine:

> http://mydomain.com/user/public/usernamehere

but if i have this i get the 404:

> http://mydomain.com/user/public/usernametwo.net

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the point to your set of allowed input.

Try this...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)$ /user/public/index.php?username=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I don't know the URL structure of your page, but a better way of rewriting would be...

```
RewriteRule ^user/public/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)$ /user/public/index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks. what is the purpose of enclosing the rewrite with **<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>** ?

Comment: The rewrite takes only part, when the mod_rewrite extension is part of your Apache installation. Otherwise it would lead to an error 500.

Comment: Why wouldn't mod_rewrite be part of your Apache installation if you're using mod_rewrite to develop your web site?

Comment: Why would you add all those `RewriteCond`-s? They change the meaning of the rewrite in ways that may not be appropriate. Maybe the rewrite should happen even if there is a filesystem object which matches the request. This is not part of the original question; just how to match the dot in the regex. Is it the right thing to bypass the redirect for user `foo` if there happens to be stray a file called `foo` in `/user/public`?

Comment: @Kaz It is a clean implementation at all. At first the "IfModule"-Section is to avoid trouble when server configuration changes however. At second you are right, but normally I do only rewrites when no file with same name exists, so I added this snipped automatically from my code lib. So xiomai you can leave out the rewrite conditions if you don't need.