# Redirect if url ONLY contains letters or numbers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website setup where users can claim "/pages", such as
mywebsite.com/example1 or mywebsite.com/example2.

If a user types in a URL that doesn't exist, it obviously redirects to a 404 error page. However, I want it so that if a user types in a non-existent URL containing *just* letters or numbers (no symbols or such), *then* it will be redirected to a page I have created stating "url available!".

I configured a this .shtml page so that when a valid URL is entered it shows this:

```
<h1>available</h1>    
<div>mywebsite.com<!--#echo var="REQUEST_URI" --> is available.</div>
```

[image: example1]
[image: example2]

However, I do not know how to set up the "validity" part. I want it to only show this page if the inputted URL only contains numbers or letters, no symbols. In other words,

```
mywebsite.com/@user goes to 404 error page  
mywebsite.com/u$er goes to 404 error page  
mywebsite.com/user_ goes to 404 error page  
mywebsite.com/user redirects to my custom page  
mywebsite.com/user123 redirects to my custom page  
mywebsite.com/123 redirects to my custom page
```

I currently have it set up where the 404 error page is the one that states "mywebsite.com/(...) is available" but this causes problems as it will say pretty much anything is available. I have tried blocking certain characters using `RewriteRule ^(.*);(.*)$ /error.shtml [L,R=301]`, where each RewriteRule detects if the url contains another symbol and does a 301 redirect to my custom error page. However, this code cannot redirect *all* symbols, for example if I put `RewriteRule ^(.*)$(.*)$ /error.shtml [L,R=301]` to redirect any uses of dollar signs in the url it gives me a server error as "$" is a reserved character. (Unless there is a workaround that I do not know of)! So I am instead going for this method, instead of **blocking** symbols, just **only** allowing letters and numbers.

Help is much appreciated! And needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following rules in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+$ custom.page [L]
```

If something exist it gets served up normally. If it doesn't exist AND the part of the request uri for the current directory only contains alphanumeric characters it goes to custom.page. If it contains something else, it goes to the default 404 page.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Peter is there a way to include periods and underscores as well?

Comment: @Cris Yes, now it works with periods and underscores too.

Comment: @Cris Look here for a reference on how [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) work.

Comment: I did the same thing with this code snippet (removed all my other code to see if that's what was interfering) and nothing =( I understand that it _should_ work and all the references and guides say the same thing, but for some reason it's not working.. It's ok, thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do that:

```
#If there is no file match
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Or a directory match
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#Redirect alphanumeric strings to your custom page
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$ /my/custom/page [R=301,L]
#If there are symbols, send to 404 
RewriteRule .* /error.shtml [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tested this out and it works too, but does it do anything that Peter's code doesn't?

Comment: We posted at exactly the same time. So pick one!

Comment: I did. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Hi @Rob is there a way to include periods and underscores as well ?

Comment: Yes, just add _. after 0-9. I've edited the answer to show this.

Comment: Hmm it seems to send a 500 Internal Server error when I type the URL with either; **edit** it seems to work only with [a-zA-Z0-9_], when I add a period it sends an error for all requests

Comment: Works for me.
/foo = custom page
/fo.o = custom page
/fo_o = custom page
/fo^o = 404

Comment: I used your code and replaced the pages with the correct ones, and all url requests sends a browser "too many redirects" error

Comment: Make sure your redirect locations have forward slashes at the beginning. I'm testing what I posted and it's working as expected on my machine.

Comment: Does the location you are redirecting to actually exist as a file? If not, this will infinitely redirect to your custom page, and you need to include a condition that filters out requests to your custom page.

Comment: Yes the file exists, I'm reading now that it has to do something with inserting a backslash before the period but its still not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621584/mod-rewrite-rule-to-include-period

Comment: You should not need to escape the period in that context. Can you post your actual rules?

Comment: I deleted all my .htaccess code and made sure this was the only thing there to see if it was any of my previous code causing the problems.  I also made the path as specific as possible. Still doesn't work. =( What do you mean by rules?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151797/discussion-between-rob-ruchte-and-cris).